# Questions with lots of long tags are cut off in the android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, questions, android-app

For example this one, [Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) (only just though)

Questions with many long tags get cut off the edge of the screen (on my Galaxy S2).

I think they should wrap to the next line.

Comment: Reproduced on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193075/meta-about-page-showing-html having the phone both vertically and horizontally.

Comment: If this does get corrected/changed, then the new behavior should be also be able to handle multiple long tags in a question, so that when tags overflow into the second or third line, the UI does not otherwise break. @Kasra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed for the next app update:

[image]

Thanks!