# Meta about page showing HTML

Tags: bug, status-completed, tour, character-escaping

I think it's another case of HTML being escaped when it shouldn't be. If you visit [the Meta About page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/about), in the first grey box:

> Meta-discussion means <span class="revision-comment"> discussion of the discussion itself instead of the actual topic of the discussion</span>.

I'm guessing that's supposed to be a real HTML span tag with some styles applied to that definition.

Comment: Programmers make mistakes?  ;)

Comment: You seem to be one of the few people today who has read the Meta About page *before* asking a question. Congratulations.

Comment: I blame Wikipedia; why they stick `<span>` tags everywhere?!

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Yeah. It's Wikipedia. Nothing to do with me. Nothing at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good spot.

Missed this bit during localization. Forgot to tell the localization code to not encode those.

Fixed.